# Cross Domain Ajax post request in IE

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, zend-framework

I'm trying to do a cross domain ajax post request within ie. Here is my code:

```
   xdr = new XDomainRequest();
   xdr.onload = loading;
   xdr.open("POST", "http://templater.pmueller.dev.xiag.ch/frontend/testlogin");
   xdr.send("customer_password="+$('#user_group__templater_login_password').val()+
            "&customer_username="+$('#user_group__templater_login_username').val());
```

And on server side, i try to parse the body of the request like:

```
if(!isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA)) {
   parse_str($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA, $_POST);
}
```

This doesn't work. $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA seems to be empty always. I've also tried to enable "always_populate_raw_post_data" but this didn't help. What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven' a clue why $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is empty. I now solved it using `php://input`

```
$post = file_get_contents('php://input');
parse_str($post, $_POST);
```

Also i've made sure, just ie request go to that piece of code, but this really depends on what you are doing.